# Unable to register user with Arabic names

Tags: ios, applozic

I am getting failed resonse while registering users with Arabic names.

**Request:**

```
PARAM_STRING USER_REGISTRATION :: {
  "contactNumber": "",
  "userTypeId": 0,
  "authenticationTypeId": 0,
  "notificationMode": 0,
  "deviceType": 4,
  "deviceApnsType": 1,
  "userId": "محمد رضوان رشيد",
  "password": "",
  "imageLink": "<image url>",
  "emailVerified": 1,
  "unreadCountType": 1,
  "appVersionCode": "106",
  "prefContactAPI": 2,
  "emailId": "محمد رضوان رشيد",
  "displayName": "محمد رضوان رشيد",
  "applicationId": "<APPLICATION_ID>"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**api error :**

```
CREATE ACCOUNT - {
  "status": "error",
  "errorResponse": [
    {
      "errorCode": "AL-I-01",
      "description": "internal server error",
      "displayMessage": "could not extract ResultSet"
    }
  ],
  "generatedAt": 1473527281694
}
```

Comment: It's an internal error with the API you're using. You'd have to look into that. I don't know the API but are you sure `userId` and `emailId` are supposed to have arabic in them (rather than ASCII?)

Comment: If `emailId` is supposed to be a legal email, the one given here is not an email address. It's a full name. Similarly can the userId really have spaces in it? Having userId, userId, and displayName all be the same (and all including spaces) is very surprising. That said, like Pekka, I'm not familiar with the service, so perhaps this is allowed and it just can't handle Arabic.

Comment: right @RobNapier in https://www.applozic.com userId is supposed to be a unique identifier for all users and arabic or spaces are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of the

> "userId": "محمد رضوان رشيد"

Arabic names are supported in display name

> "displayName": "محمد رضوان رشيد"

UserId should be unique for each user and it should be alpha numeric without any spaces, +, *, $ or any special characters.